# Core Data: is performing NSFetches in transient property code bad? Why?

Tags: ios

In Core Data, we can put transient properties in our entity objects (or categories on our entities). These transient properties can calculate transient data based on actual entity properties.

Is putting code that does NSFetchRequests in transient properties over the top and to be avoided? I feel this use is beyond the remit of a transient property, but I'm trying to express why this isn't a good idea. What are the downsides?